How can I create this type of visualisation using Python?
I have csv file containing some hierarchical data and I’d like to create a visualisation like this:

Anybody know how I can do this, preferably using matplotlib?

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
data = {
'Scope': ['Scope Insertion', 'Scope Positioning', 'No Action'],
'Instrument': ['Instrument Insertion', 'Instrument Positioning', 'No Action'],
'Site': ['Fluid Wash', 'Debris Wash', 'No Action'],
'Pressure': ['Inflate Pressure', 'Deflate Pressure', 'No Action']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
palette = {
'Scope Insertion': '#4CAF50',
'Scope Positioning': '#AED581',
'No Action': '#EEEEEE',
'Instrument Insertion': '#1E88E5',
'Instrument Positioning': '#90CAF9',
'Fluid Wash': '#FFB74D',
'Debris Wash': '#8D6E63',
'Inflate Pressure': '#9E9E9E',
'Deflate Pressure': '#757575'
}
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 2))
sns.heatmap(
df.applymap(palette.get).replace(palette),
annot=df,
fmt='',
cmap=palette,
cbar=False,
linewidths=.5,
ax=ax
)
ax.set_title('Setup')
ax.set_xlabel('Setup')
ax.set_ylabel('GT')
plt.show()


Thank you! I think I understand most of it. But could you say more about why you did the replace(palette)?

applymap(palette.get) already transforms each value to its corresponding color, the replace(palette) ensures to transform again where necessary.

Ah ok. That’s what was throwing me off since it seemed to be redundant.

Honestly, you are true. replace(palette) is essentially redundant in this context because df.applymap(palette.get) has already done the job of converting categorical values to colors.

I'm getting the following error when I run it:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '#4CAF50'
